# Packing an integer number to 3 bytes in Python

Tags: python

With background knowledge of C I want to serialize an integer number to 3 bytes. I searched a lot and found out I should use struct packing. I want something like this:

```
number = 1195855
buffer = struct.pack("format_string", number)
```

Now I expect buffer to be something like `['\x12' '\x3F' '\x4F']`. Is it also possible to set endianness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, using either `>` or `<` in your format string:

```
import struct

number = 1195855

def print_buffer(buffer):
    print(''.join(["%02x" % ord(b) for b in buffer]))   # Python 2
    #print(buffer.hex())                                # Python 3


# Little Endian
buffer = struct.pack("<L", number)
print_buffer(buffer)                # 4f3f1200

# Big Endian
buffer = struct.pack(">L", number)
print_buffer(buffer)                # 00123f4f
```

- [2.x docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)
- [3.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)

Note, however, that you're going to have to figure out how you want to get rid of the empty byte in the buffer, since `L` will give you 4 bytes and you only want 3.

Something like:

```
buffer = struct.pack("<L", number)
print_buffer(buffer[:3])            # 4f3f12

# Big Endian
buffer = struct.pack(">L", number)
print_buffer(buffer[-3:])           # 123f4f
```

would be one way.

Comment: `buffer = struct.pack(">L", number)[1:]` will do the trick of dropping the first byte.

Comment: `assert [hex(b) for b in struct.pack('>L', 1195855)[1:]] == ['0x12', '0x3f', '0x4f']`

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hex'. What does this error say?

Comment: @saeed It means you're using Python 2 (I used Python 3).  I updated my answer to include a way for you to get the same output as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to manually pack the bytes:

```
>>> import struct
>>> number = 1195855
>>> data = struct.pack('BBB',
...     (number >> 16) & 0xff,
...     (number >> 8) & 0xff,
...     number & 0xff,
... )
>>> data
b'\xa5Z'
>>> list(data)
[18, 63, 79]
```

As just the 3-bytes, it's a bit redundant since the last 3 parameters of `struct.pack` equals the `data`. But this worked well in my case because I had header and footer bytes surrounding the unsigned 24-bit integer.

Whether this method, or slicing is more elegant is up to your application. I found this was cleaner for my project.